# Using Twig to show object properties that start with a hash

Tags: php, oop, hash, twig

I am building a template using Twig to show my last.fm top artist chart. Part of the last.fm api returns images of each artist - when converted to a php object using `json_decode`, it looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
    ["#text"]=>
        string(49) "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/78224120.png"
    ["size"]=>
        string(5) "small"
}
```

Using PHP, I can reference this using `Object->{#text}`. I've tried a few approaches in Twig - `Object.#text`, `Object[#text]`, etc - but keep getting `Unexpected character #`.

How do I do reference this property in Twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand:

```
 $template->render(array('obj', $obj));

 {{ attribute(obj, '#text') }}`
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's just what I was after. Thanks!